# How to use Curlpp to write json data file?

Tags: c, json, libcurl, curlpp

command line option is working,below is the wokring request

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json"   https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=apikey -d @sync-request.json
```

The same iam trying to do using libcurl ,Adding json data file is getting failed...
Working when directly pass json data as string in curl::PostFields.

apikey replaced with mydev key on below example.
for large file size need this option.

```
#include <iostream>
 #include <curlpp/Options.hpp>
 #include <curlpp/Easy.hpp>
 #include <curlpp/cURLpp.hpp>
 #include <sstream>
 #include <future>
 #include <curlpp/Exception.hpp>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <cstdio>
 #include <cstring>
 #include <cerrno>

    size_t WriteCallback(char* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *f)
    {
        FILE *file = (FILE *)f;
        cout<<"file write"<<endl;
        return fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, file);
    }

    std::future<std::string> invoke(std::string const& url) {
      return std::async(std::launch::async, 
        [](std::string const& url) mutable {
          std::list<std::string> header;
          header.push_back("Content-Type: application/json");

          FILE* file = fopen("sync-request.json", "wb");
          curlpp::options::WriteFunctionCurlFunction  myFunction(WriteCallback);
          curlpp::OptionTrait<void *, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA> myData(file);

          curlpp::Cleanup clean;
          curlpp::Easy r;
          r.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Url(url));
          r.setOpt(new curlpp::options::HttpHeader(header));
          r.setOpt(myFunction);
          r.setOpt(myData);

          std::ostringstream response;
          r.setOpt(new curlpp::options::WriteStream(&response));

          r.perform();
          std::cout<<std::string(response.str());
          return std::string(response.str());
        }, url);
    }
    int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        invoke("https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=apikey");
        return 0;
    }
```

throws error

```
  <p>The requested URL <code>/v1/speech:recognize?key=apikey</code> was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you load your Json file content into a string, you can simply set your data as POST payload.

```
    string payload = json.data();
    [...]
    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFields(payload));
    request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::PostFieldSize(payload.length()));
    [...]
    request.perform();
```